# ACR TASK tagging

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I am creating one ACR task with below script in azure cli to patch my azure container image when base image is updated and its working fine.

az acr task create 
--registry Myregistry 
--name myacrtask 
--image myimage:{{.Run.ID}} 
--context https://dev.azure.com/testaccount/myproject/_git/acr-build-helloworld-node.git#master 
--file Dockerfile-app 
--commit-trigger-enabled true 
--base-image-trigger-enabled true 
--git-access-token *****************************

Now my image having tag with "Run ID" as you can see in my command which is getting generated when task is running.

Now I want to create a custom tag like CurrentDate and some text like below.

if today's date is 09032020 then tag should be like
09032020_sometext

I am not sure how i can generate this kind of tag on the place of run id. I tried like

```
--image myimage:{{$(date +'%m%d%Y-BAU')}}
```

but no luck..

Any suggestion will be really apprecited.

Thanks
Rajiv

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the tag like this in the command:

```
--image myimage:$(date +%m%d%Y)-BAU
```

Then it will work fine. And the tag will like this:

[image]

And if you want the tag like `09032020_sometext`, maybe you need to change the `-` into `_`.

Comment: How to have a static tag for task images?